# Mailchimp v3 api returns error

Tags: php, curl, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I wrote curl request to get automation link. But it returns 401.
I just need automation list by GET call. 
I'm not clear what is wrong is my code. I believe curl call is good.
Any ideas?

```
// Here is the data we will be sending to the service
  $some_data = array(
    'apikey' => 'xxxxxxxxwqew3423xxxxx'
  );  

  $curl = curl_init();
  // You can also set the URL you want to communicate with by doing this:
  // $curl = curl_init('http://localhost/echoservice');

  // We POST the data
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  // Set the url path we want to call
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us13.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/automations');  
  // Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // Insert the data
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $some_data);

  // You can also bunch the above commands into an array if you choose using: curl_setopt_array

  // Send the request
  $result = curl_exec($curl);

  // Get some cURL session information back
  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);  

  print_r($info);
  echo 'content type: ' . $info['content_type'] . '<br />';
  echo 'http code: ' . $info['http_code'] . '<br />';

  // Free up the resources $curl is using
  curl_close($curl);

  echo $result;
```

Response is:

```
http code: 401
{"type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/","title":"API Key Missing","status":401,"detail":"Your request did not include an API key.","instance":"xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxx"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue.

API key should contain server number. Example, for me server was u13,
so api is: dfsdfsdfsdffsdfsdf-u13